# How to add a news section and add links to phpbb forum

Tags: forum, phpbb

Hey there im in the middle of editing my site, and i came across this site, and am looking to get my site as the same layout with the navigation bars and such, but im new to phpbb so am stuck :( here is the site http://www.3commandobrigade.com/

when you go to the home tab it shows all the posts that are posted in the "News" section under the category General forums

and also how do i add the nav links like on that site, so it has Home, Forum, Schedule, i was under the idea it was something like "Nav Links"
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That forum is using a phpBB Extension called Portal. I haven't found a new version of that mod/extension but here is a [link](https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=456&t=2259081) to a version made for the phpbb 3.1.3 which should be compatible with the current version. You should be able to create two columns of news in the admin panel if you want so, but it should be some work.